# create method to return id when substring matches with column in database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I just want to create a method in databasehandler class to search a substring in column and return row id with the use of cursor.

Just like the given SQL Query :

```
SELECT id FROM TABLE_CONTACTS WHERE phone LIKE %phone%;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer of the question :

```
    // here id is primary key of my database of string data type
    String getIDIfPhone(String phone) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String id = null;
    String phone1 = "%" + phone + "%";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + ID + " FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS +
            " WHERE " + PHONE + " LIKE ?",new String[]{phone1});

    if (c!=null)
    {
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ID));
        }
    }
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String getIDIfPhone(String phone) { 
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 

  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + ID + " FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE " + PHONE + " LIKE %"+phone+"%",new String[] {id});
  if(c.moveToFirst()){ 
    int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
    return id; 
  } else { 
    return id; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me the code of method having cursor?

Comment: @ShahbazHashmi check it

Comment: My code is // get id from number
    String getIDIfPhone(String phone) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String id=null;
       Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + ID + " FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS +
                " WHERE " + PHONE + " LIKE %"+phone+"%",new String[] {id});


        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            return id;
        }else{
            return id;
        }
    }

Comment: Sir, you created a method of string return type. And trying to return integer. How can this is possible ?